# How do you set up a second VNC session?

Tags: remote-desktop

On mac, you can enable a VNC host using screen sharing, and can access it via either screen sharing or a normal VNC client by forwarding port 5900.

How can one set up a second VNC session?  I want this in particular because my desktop (host) and laptop (client) have different screen size and resolution.

Comment: It might be helpful if you expanded on exactly what you're hoping to achieve here. You want to open two VNC connections from your laptop to your desktop?

Comment: I'd like to be able to create a VNC server session with a resolution different from the native resolution on my server.  It would also be nice to open a second graphical session on the host itself, e.g. using Chicken of the VNC viewing port 5901.  Is this possible?